# How to manage multiple products that share code

Tags: project-management, release-management

The company I just joined has a system of products that share a large percentage of their code base (via shared links in Visual SourceSafe).  There are about 25 product types in this system as well as a PC interface.

The products network together using proprietary protocols that are largely undocumented.  Historically, the method for maintaining this mess is to require that all firmware and software is released as a package.  This, of course, causes significant delays in release schedules due to the required regression testing.

Has anyone else had a successful method of dealing with this type of issue?  We're really getting beat up over it by management (I honestly can't fault them for feeling this way).

My first thoughts are to try to separate the device releases from each other somehow.  Maybe pull shared functionality into libraries which are versioned.  Then only update devices that use the libraries that have changed.  I see issues with version mismatches from this however.

This is an organizational question.  I understand how to keep the house of cards going via testing and processes, but I believe that better organization of the code base could have many good results.

I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score -1):

> significant delays in release schedules due to the required regression testing.

That's why folks do a "[daily build](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_build)".

> Daily builds typically include a set of tests, sometimes called a
>   smoke test ( as in where there is smoke there is fire). These tests
>   are included to assist in determining what may have been broken by the
>   changes included in the latest build. The critical piece of this
>   process is to include new and revised tests as the project progresses.

When the organization -- as a whole -- has to keep the daily build working, then people change their responsibilities, points of view, biases, complaints and actions to keep the daily build running.

Daily stand-up meetings become focused on things that might break the build.

Individual developers have to refactor their code more carefully to avoid breaking the build.

Breaking the build becomes an immediate, instantaneous indicator of something being out of sync.  Immediate.  No delay.  If I break the build today, everyone will know it tomorrow morning.  No days were wasted assuming (or hoping) that things still worked.  We can immediately roll changes back, or apply changes to keep going forward.

Comment: We do.  That keeps it compiling.  I assume you also mean automated testing after the daily builds.  I want to do this, but we just don't have the infrastructure at the moment.  This isn't PC software, so there's a significant effort to do the automated testing.

Comment: " just don't have the infrastructure at the moment".  That's not relevant.  You asked what to do.  You're not alone.  Everyone else who has this problem solves it with a daily build that runs the unit test.  That's pretty much the standard solution.  If you don't have the infrastructure, that doesn't change the solution any, does it?

Comment: The costs (money, time) are always relevant.  No it doesn't remove it as an option, but it does help assign a priority.  I'm sorry if it sounded like I was disagreeing.  I totally agree, but need to consider all options.  What you are saying simply doesn't fix it all.

Comment: @caveman: "What you are saying simply doesn't fix it all"?  Why not?  It's the standard solution.  What doesn't it fix?

Comment: There are organizational issues here as well.  Smoke tests are not a silver bullet.

Comment: @caveman: Right now you have no unit testing.  You're saying that a minimal smoke test will not help at all?  How's that possible?  Do you already have a smoke test in place?  I don't get what you're saying?  Nobody ever said anything about a magical "silver bullet" did they?  Did I miss something in the wikipedia article?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3111/discussion-between-caveman-and-s-lott)

Comment: @caveman: why chat?  The standard answer is a daily build with testing.  If that can't work, you need to **update** your question to provide some criteria for success which cannot be satisfied by a daily build. I'm sorry that it takes time and money and leads to disruptive, expensive changes.  There is no "faery dust" that can be sprinkled around to make things magically work.  Can you provide an **update** to the question so that I can see some reason why the standard solution doesn't apply in your unique situation?

Comment: @caveman: I see that you simply don't like the standard solution that most folks uses to address your problem.  Most folks use a daily build to prevent the significant delays in getting every package in sync.  You are free to **not** do that.  However, your comments still make little sense because they don't present any new data on your problem, and the solution to your problem remains as doing a daily build.  A daily build is not magic.  It not solve all the world's problems.  It is considered a best practice by people with your problem.  If you want to add facts to your question, please do.

Comment: The website suggests chat.  I went with it.  Refactoring is also a standard solution. Testing finds bugs.  Refactoring helps to keep code logical and reduce the *creation* of bugs.  In any case, I didn't want a philosophical (or any other kind of) argument. I basically said "point taken, got anything else" and all I got in return was "Nope, that'll solve it all."

Comment: "Nope, that'll solve it all."?  Really?  All?  I don't believe I said it would solve all of your problems.  I never said silver bullet, either.  I'm trying to make a point here.  The daily build has **more** impact that refactoring or testing.  Is that clear?  You wanted advice.  I'm trying to provide advice.  You appear to object to the advice I'm providing.  Is that the case?  You don't like the advice you're getting?